# Renaming the tag geometrical isomerism

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have a tag [geometrical-isomerism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometrical-isomerism).

The IUPAC Gold Book defines this ([DOI: 10.1351/goldbook.G02620](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.G02620)):

> **geometric isomerism** [obsolete]
> Obsolete synonym for cis-trans isomerism. (Usage strongly discouraged).

I know that the term is still very, very popular in some textbooks; however, I think we should follow the IUPAC recommendation and rename the tag. I don't think there is much need for debate, but there is a question remaining: Should we keep a synonym?

Comment: Cis-trans is itself not a great description - mostly superseded by E-Z.

Comment: @Mithoron cis and trans goes beyond alkenes, it includes disubstituted rings, for example.

Comment: @orthocresol Sure does, but doesn't contain all E-Z so isn't equal to "geometric isomerism", even if its name is rather lame :)

Comment: @Mithoron E/Z is nomenclature. It is part of CIP just as R/S are. You can have cis-trans isomers needing E/Z designations and you can have ones that need R/S nomenclature. So I would actually claim the opposite of you.

Comment: Using a synonym will be better than renaming as someone will unavoidably recreate the tag and it might get away unnoticed.